# Purescript - How to define function signature in REPL?

Tags: purescript

When I type, say:

```
f :: Int -> Int
```

The REPL complaints with:

```
The type declaration for f should be followed by its definition.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REPL expects each single line to be a complete program, and since a lonely signature is not a complete program, you get an error.

In order to make the REPL ingest several lines before trying to compile them, use the `:paste` command to begin the block and then hit Ctrl+D to end it:

```
> :paste
… f :: Int -> Int
… f x = x + 42
… ^D
> f 1
43
```

This and other commands can be discovered by typing `:?`, as the REPL invites you to do at the beginning of the session:

```
PSCi, version 0.13.6
Type :? for help
```